# Coding exercise to check for pangrams

Tags: python

Running through the Functions and Methods homework for Jose Portillos python course and I wrote this for the last problem:

```
import string
 
def ispangram(str1):
    alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase
    x=0
    for y in set(str1):
        if y.lower() in alphabet:
            x+=1
    return x
```

I was just going to check that x returned 26 and then change the code to `return x==26` to check for pangrams. But for some reason with the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" it's returning 27 instead of 26.

Can anyone explain why that might be so? I can figure out a fix easily enough, but I have no idea why I'm getting this result.

Comment: It's because `'t'` and `'T'` aren't the same thing. So the set that you get from `set(str1)` contains both of them. You want to do this `set(str1.lower())` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting the string to lower **after** converting it to a set, in which case `T` and `t` are treated as different characters, as they should be.

P.S.: Issues are like these are excellent cases for learning how to use a debugger. (Not being snarky, genuine tip.)

Answer (score 0):

If you observe carefully your sentence 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' it contains T two times and T as capital caused due to lower function. While your function does not have capability to count it once. Although you can solve this problem by

1. write y only instead of y.lower()

   if y in alphabet:
   x+=1
2. Or either count for repeated alphabet which it will count as once only

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to iterate over a string here, you do not need to convert the string to a set.

```
 
def ispangram(str1):
    alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase
    x=0
    for y in str1:
        if y.lower() in alphabet:
            x+=1
    return x

Hope this helps :)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if I don't convert to a string then `x` ends up counting every character in the string rather than just the unique characters, which would give me the same issue I have now.